# How to unmarshal JSON into protobuf containing oneof definitions using jsonpb?

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers

I'm currently failing to unmarshal a JSON snippet which is generated by *jsonpb*. Maybe it's just some kind of misunderstanding on my side, but when looking at the tests I'd expect it to work somehow.

Here's the relevant snippet of the `pb.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package pb;

message Parameter {
    string name = 1;
    oneof value {
        string str_value = 2;
        int32 int_value = 3;
        bool bool_value = 4;
        float float_value = 5;
    }
}

message ParameterSet {
    bytes raw = 1;
    repeated Parameter parameters = 2;
}

message ParameterSets {
    map<string,ParameterSet> sets = 1;
}
```

Testing marshaling/unmarshaling using this simple snippet fails:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gogo/protobuf/jsonpb"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
    str, err := m.MarshalToString(&pb.ParameterSets{Sets: map[string]*pb.ParameterSet{
        "parameter": {
            Raw: []byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2},
            Parameters: []*pb.Parameter{
                {Name: "itest", Value: &pb.Parameter_IntValue{42}},
                {Name: "stest", Value: &pb.Parameter_StrValue{"Foobar"}},
                {Name: "btest", Value: &pb.Parameter_BoolValue{true}},
                {Name: "ftest", Value: &pb.Parameter_FloatValue{41.99}},
           },
        },
    }},)
    fmt.Println(str)
    fmt.Println(err)

    sets := pb.ParameterSets{}
    err = jsonpb.Unmarshal(strings.NewReader(str), &sets)
    fmt.Println(sets)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

It results in:

```
{"sets":{"parameter":{"raw":"AAECAwQFBgEC","parameters":[{"name":"itest","intValue":42},{"name":"stest","strValue":"Foobar"},{"name":"btest","boolValue":true},{"name":"ftest","floatValue":41.99}]}}}
<nil>
{map[]}
unknown field "intValue" in pb.Parameter
```

How can I get the *oneof* values back in the proto object?

Comment: can we have the contents of the generated pb.go file?

Comment: @RickyA currently wondering why I can't reproduce it with the snippet above which just doesn't contain the whole story of the project. Trying to find the reason... Will report back.

Comment: Now I've a working and a non working version. It is not related to the generated `.pb.go` file, but has something to do with a `vendor` directory inside of my `proto`-Repository. If I remove it, the oneof key in JSON is **int_value** and the unmarshalling works. If the vendor directory is there, the oneof key in JSON is **intValue** - and it does not work. The vendor directory only contains `github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto` with some go-files. They're in the same version as the top level ones.

Comment: Placed it here: https://github.com/cajus/prototest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Type mix up due to the two vendor folders. A type declared in two vendor folders is *not the same, even if the code for them is exactly the same*.

Thus for example:
`prototest-master/vendor/github.com/gogo/proto/messageSet` (A) is not of the same type as `prototest-master/`**proto**`/vendor/github.com/gogo/proto/messageSet` (B) even as their imports are the same (`github.com/gogo/proto`)

In your project's `main.go` the construction of the marshaler `jsonpb.Marshaler{}` uses the types from (A) where the actual messages like `&pb.ParameterSets{...` use the types from (B) to construct itself.

Since `jsonpb` seems to do a lot of reflection stuff it breaks on the mixing of the two types.

A better solution is to use just one `vendor` folder to be clear on the types everyone uses. I would just ditch the (B) vendor folder because it adds nothing.

Comment: The problem is that the real project has vendored *proto* which has vendored gogo/*. The main project does so, too. The only way to get around it seems to be removing of the proto/vendor stuff. I can make it happen, but that needs some refactoring. Sigh. If I dislike something in golang, then it's its various ways of broken dependency management. But anyway - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is safe to manually build the message as you are doing since you cannot grant that the resulting JSON matches exactly what would be produced by `jsonpb.Marshal`. Better to just instantiate `Parameter`.
[This github issue](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/446) discusses a scenario that is in a way similar to yours and [one of the solutions](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/446#issuecomment-360698636) may help you:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
)

func main() {
    msg := &Person{
        Name: "Allen",
        Age: 30,
        Married: true,
        Number: &Person_F{float32(14500.6)},
    }

    m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
    js, err := m.MarshalToString(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("json output ==> %v\n", js)

    msg2 := &Person{}
    if err := jsonpb.Unmarshal(strings.NewReader(js), msg2); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", proto.MarshalTextString(msg2))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***2022 Update**: I haven't been able to find a good answer to this online so figured I'd share my own with the caveat that I'm far from sure if this is the best approach.*

If you have a proto like this:

```
message WrapperProto {
   string answer_to_the_universe = 1;
   ProtoWithOneof oneof_example = 2;
}

message ProtoWithOneof {
  oneof option {
    string string_option = 1;
    uint32 int_option = 2;
  }
}
```

You'll need to add the following code snippet in the same package/directory where the `.pb.go` file is compiled to:

```golang
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"

func (p *ProtoWithOneof) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    return protojson.Unmarshal(data, p)
}
```

And then, when unmarshalling `WrapperProto`, you can configure your json string like so:

```json
{
  "answer_to_the_universe": "42",
  "oneof_example": {
     "string_option": "I am a string"
  }
}
```

or like so:

```json
{
  "answer_to_the_universe": "42",
  "oneof_example": {
     "int_option": 69
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach works and correctly uses `protojson` instead of `jsonpb` pkg. The only downside, of course, is that you have to manually implement this method in a folder where everything else is generated code... why the compiler isn't generating this itself, though, is a separate question.

Comment: Edit queue is full, but one correction needs to be made: in the `UnmarshalJSON` implementation, don't return `nil`, but instead `return protojson.Unmarshal(data, p)` -- that way if an error occurs it will be propagated up correctly.